# docker-compose ps with non-default docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am relatively new to using docker-compose and am running a stack with the following command

```
docker-compose \
  --project-name version-12 \
  -f installation/docker-compose-common.yml \
  -f installation/docker-compose-erpnext.yml \
  --project-directory installation \
  up -d
```

now, with the non-default `docker-compose.yml` files I can't manage to have `docker-compose stop`, `docker-compose ps` to work. I have tried to use the `-f`, or `--project-name` flags but couldn't make it happen.

Can anyone kindly advise how to make this work in such a scenario?

Comment: what happens when you give `docker-compose -f installation/docker-compose-common.yml ps `

Comment: not enough detail. You actually need to repeat the all options of the command used to fire `up` the stack and replace the initial `up` with whatever you want `docker-compose` to do for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to repeat all of the `docker-compose` options for every command you need to run.

There are two ways around this.  One is to write a shell script wrapper that invokes this command:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# I am `docker-compose-erpnext.sh`
# Run me with any normal `docker-compose` options
exec docker-compose \
  --project-name version-12 \
  -f installation/docker-compose-common.yml \
  -f installation/docker-compose-erpnext.yml \
  --project-directory installation \
  "$@"
```

Docker Compose also supports [environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/) for most of its settings; many of these in turn can also be included in a [`.env` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/).  You can't specify `--project-directory` this way, but it's [documented](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/) to default to the directory of the Compose file.

```sh
export COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=version-12
export COMPOSE_FILE=installation/docker-compose-common.yml:installation/docker-compose-erpnext.yml
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose ps
```

You can put these two settings in a file name `.env` in the directory from which you're running `docker-compose` (not the `installation` subdirectory); but if you have multiple deployments you're trying to manage, you can't specify an alternate name for the file (there is neither a CLI option nor an environment variable setting for it).

Comment: _"You need to repeat all of the docker-compose options for every command you need to run."_ ... spot on, thx. I'll look into the other suggestions which will take a bit I guess